# Connect to private ip address - graphql - kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, graphql

How to connect `graphql` api which is on private network and accessible through private ip address. My frontend server and api is on the `VNET`.

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client'

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
    uri: 'http://10.0.0.10:3000'+'/api'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: uploadLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
export default client
```

Both applications are running on `kubernetes` same cluster different pods. Private services are accessible within cluster and when I `exec` into the frontend pod I am able to access `graphql` end point with private ip address.

But, On the browser, it's not connecting and giving this error: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

> frontend (public ip) --> graphql (private ip)

Answer (score 1):

The 3 main methods for accessing an internal kubernetes service from outside are: **NodePort**, **LoadBalancer**, and **Ingress**.

You can read about some of the main differences between them here https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0

---

## NodePort

### Map a randomly or manually selected high port from a certain range to a service on a 1 to 1 basis.

Either allow kubernetes to randomly select a high port, or manually define a high port from a predefined range which is by default 30000–32767 (but can be changed), and map it to an internal service port on a 1 to 1 basis.

Warning: Although it is possible to manually define a NodePort port number per service, it is generally not recommended due to possible issues such as port conflicts. So in most cases, you should let the cluster randomly select a NodePort port number for you.

From official docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

> If you set the type field to NodePort, the Kubernetes master will
> allocate a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range
> flag (default: 30000-32767), and each Node will proxy that port (the
> same port number on every Node) into your Service.

---

## LoadBalancer

### Attach a service to an external ip provided by an IP Provider service such as a cloud provider Public IP Service.

The functionality of this service type depends on external drivers/plugins. Most modern clouds offer support to supply public IPs for LoadBalancer definitions. But if you are spinning a custom cluster with no means to assign public IPs (such as with Rancher with no IP provider plugins), the best you can probably do with this is assign an IP of a host machine to a single service.

From the official docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

> On cloud providers which support external load
> balancers, setting the type field to LoadBalancer will provision a
> load balancer for your Service. The actual creation of the load
> balancer happens asynchronously, and information about the provisioned
> balancer will be published in the Service’s .status.loadBalancer
> field.

---

## Ingress

### Run a central application router service which receives all traffic on a certain port (or ports) and routes it to services based on parameters like the requested domain and path.

To install it you must create an application router service (such as nginx) which runs in your cluster and analyzes every new resource of type Ingress that is created. Then you create Ingress resource that define the routing rules you would like such as which DNS request to listen to and which service to forward the request to.

Although multiple solutions exist for this purpose, I recommend Nginx Ingress

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Official Docs:

> What is Ingress? Typically, services and pods have IPs only routable
> by the cluster network. All traffic that ends up at an edge router is
> either dropped or forwarded elsewhere. Conceptually, this might look
> like:
>
> ```
> internet
>     |   ------------   [ Services ] An Ingress is a collection of rules that allow inbound connections to reach the cluster services.
>
> internet
>     |    [ Ingress ]    --|-----|--    [ Services ] It can be configured to give services externally-reachable URLs, load balance
> ```
>
> traffic, terminate SSL, offer name based virtual hosting, and more.
> Users request ingress by POSTing the Ingress resource to the API
> server. An Ingress controller is responsible for fulfilling the
> Ingress, usually with a loadbalancer, though it may also configure
> your edge router or additional frontends to help handle the traffic in
> an HA manner.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. But, I don't want to expose private API to the public. It can be accessible only from frontend service. And as you can see my javascript code private service is being called from outside. How can I make it so that request routes through my frontend app which is inside the cluster (frontend is exposed to the outside world)?

Comment: Many kubernetes installations include automatic DNS which creates a DNS entry for every service created.

You can refer to services in the following way:

both services in the same namespace: `servicename:port`  -- 

services in the same cluster, different namespace: `servicename.namespace:port`

Comment: @RonakPatel ultimately if you want to access anything that is inside a cluster form outside the cluster (browser) it is considered public in the clusters terms (external to the cluster) which means you probably need to implement one of the solutions mentioned above to access it. You can in turn restrict that method. In example, if you are running ingress on port 80 of your server you can restrict all port 80 traffic to your cluster machines, via a firewall

Answer (score 0):

You seem to answer your own question: that IP address is private.
You'll want to set a service definition in order to expose it to the public.